# jquery - add "active" class to children elements

Tags: jquery

Need to add an active class to my parent element if a user clicks on the child element in a list.  The below script is used if a user clicks on the parent link.

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var str=location.href.toLowerCase(); 
$('.body-content-container-pascrc ul#pascrc-sitenav li a').each(function() { 
if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) { 
$(this).attr("class","active"); //hightlight parent tab 
} 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li> <a href="#" id="agenda-link">Agenda</a>
    <ul id="agenda" class="megamenu">
      <li><a href="#">June 8, 2011</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">June 9, 2011</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">June 10, 2011</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".body-content-container-pascrc ul#pascrc-sitenav li a").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/switz/csgej/

Comment: Thanks Switz, but once the user clicks on a child element, for example: June 8, 2011, an "active" class needs to show on the parent li.

**<ul id="navigation">
<li> <a href="#" id="agenda-link" class="active">Agenda</a>**


Make sense?

Comment: That's what happens? Do you mean on the anchor tag or on the parent? Your code shows the anchor tag, whereas you're saying the parent. My code gives the parent `li` the `active` class.

Comment: So when I click on June 8 in fiddle the script adds "active" to June 8.  **<li class="active"><a href="#">June 8, 2011</a></li>**.  I need the script to also add "active" to the parent.  Which is **<li> <a id="agenda-link" href="#">Agenda</a>**.  I hope I explained properly.

Comment: you're not really being clear.  the parent *is* `li`.  This is pulled directly from the fiddle:  `<ul id="navigation"><li> <a href="#" id="agenda-link">Agenda</a><ul id="agenda" class="megamenu">****<li class="active">****<a href="#">June 8, 2011</a></li><li><a href="#">June 9, 2011</a></li><li><a href="#">June 10, 2011</a></li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: OK so you're also getting me confused. Here's the code:  `<ul id="navigation">
<li> <a href="#" id="agenda-link">Agenda</a>
<ul id="agenda" class="megamenu">
<li><a href="#">June 8, 2011</a></li>
<li><a href="#">June 9, 2011</a></li>
<li><a href="#">June 10, 2011</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>`
When a user clicks on `<li><a href="#">June 8, 2011</a></li>`. The active class should be added to `<li class="active"><a href="#">June 8, 2011</a></li>` and `<li class="active"><a href="#" id="agenda-link">Agenda</a>`